# how to center a button with css and html

Tags: css

i want to center one button up and the other down. how can i edit my css to achieve this.here is

css-

```
#ContactForm .button {
margin-left:8px;
margin-left:9px;
float:right;
margin-right:2px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:700;
color:#fff;
line-height:35px;
width:90px;
text-align:center;
background:url(../images/button_form.gif) top repeat-x #308da2;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);
position:relative;
text-decoration:none
}
```

html-

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">send</a>
  <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()">clear</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "center one button up and the other down" You mean such as vertical alignment?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsfiddle with what you want.... http://jsfiddle.net/xgdVM/

you can set the text-align of the container to center
and set the display property of the buttons to block..

CSS:

```
#form{text-align:center;}
a{display:block;}​
```

HTML

```
 <div id="form">
     <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">send</a>
     <a href="#" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()">clear</a>
 </div>​
```

OR if your buttons have a set witdth i.e `width:70px;` then you can just give them the css property `margin:0 auto;` and they will be centered by applying equal margins to the left and right

http://jsfiddle.net/xgdVM/2/

Comment: that doesn't work, the buttons are 70px, here is what your code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/xgdVM/1/. `text-align: center` will only work if the buttons are `inline-block` and you would need to use a `<br>`

Comment: true, I had this in mind as I worked on something yesterday where there could be no width set but items still had to be positioned centre. if the buttons have set width then **margin:0 auto;** is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

If you mean center horizontally:

```
#ContactForm .button {
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers, provided there's a width set */
    display: block;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:35px;
    width:90px; /* width set */
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../images/button_form.gif) top repeat-x #308da2;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none
}
```